# On Uniform Elementary Estimates of Arithmetic Sums Error Term

Tags: elementary-number-theory, arithmetic-functions, dirichlet-series

Stefan A. Burr's paper "On Uniform Elementary Estimates of Arithmetic Sums" has this result:

> *Suppose*
> $G(s)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{g(n)}{n^s},$ $G_2(s)=|g(1)|+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{|g(n)|\log{n}}{n^s},$
>
> *and define $\tau_r(n)$ to be the number of ways $n$ can be expressed as a product of $r$ factors.*
> *Let $f$ be an arithmetic function and let $g$ be such that,*
>
> $f(n)=\sum_{d|n}g(d)\tau_r(\frac{n}{d}),$
>
> *with $r\geq2$ and suppose that $G_2(1)$ exists. Then,*
>
> $\sum_{n\leq{x}}f(n)=\frac{1}{(r-1)!}G(1)x\log^{r-1}x+O\Big(G_2(1)x\log^{r-2}x\Big).$

Burr then states for $r=2$, using the average order of the divisor function:

$\sum_{n\leq{x}}\tau_2(n)=x\log{x}+(2\gamma-1)x+O(x^{1/2}),$

that with "a little work" we may find:

> $\sum_{n\leq{x}}f(n)=G(1)x\log{x}+(G'(1)+(2\gamma-1)G(1))x+$**E(x)**,
>
> *with $|$**E(x)**$|\leq8G_2(\alpha)x^{\alpha}$ for all $x\geq1$ and all $\alpha\leq1$ for which $G_2(\alpha)$ exists.*

I want to understand how he has found the bound for the error term **E(x)**. I have reached this step:

> $\sum_{n\leq{x}}f(n)=G(1)x\log{x}+(G'(1)+(2\gamma-1)G(1))x-x\log{x}\sum_{d>x}\frac{g(d)}{d}+x\sum_{d>x}\frac{g(d)\log{d}}{d}-(2\gamma-1)x\sum_{d>x}\frac{g(d)}{d}+O(x^{1/2}\sum_{d\leq{x}}\frac{g(d)}{d^{1/2}}).$

I am now unsure what steps Burr takes to reduce these excess sums into the simple error term. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: $g$ is any arithmetic function?